# Docker gerenciamento remoto

Tags: docker

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução (aplicação) que basicamente cria um WebService para comunicação entre um app Android e um Banco de Dados.
Minha duvida agora é como vou gerenciar e distribuir essa solução. Pelo que eu estudei até agora, o Docker vai ser uma mão na roda, pois posso criar os contêiner com todas as configurações necessárias, e nos meu clientes basta instalar o Docker e baixar os contêiner pelo docker hub.

Minha duvida é;
Existe alguma ferramenta para gerenciar o Docker remotamente da seguinte maneira?

Vou instalar e configurar o Docker com os contêiner da minha aplicação em 10 computadores de empresas diferente (ou mais). 
Gostaria de monitorar, gerenciar todos os Docker cada computador em um único lugar.

Outra coisa importante é que, quando houver alguma atualização da minha aplicação ou se houver a necessidade de fazer alguns ajustes em todos os Docker ou apenas em um especifico, eu gostaria de fazer esse tipo de manutenção pelo gerenciador.

Alguém conhece alguma solução parecida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O monitoramento do Docker pode ser feito com DataDog. A gestão pode ser feita com DockerCloud ou Rancher, de forma centralizada.

Sob sua ótica de fazer deploy de containers nos seus clientes, há alguns aspectos a serem considerados:

> Cada container é uma instância live de uma imagem, que por sua vez é
>   uma foto de um processo/app e suas dependências, assim, cada update
>   deveria causar um drop do container e sua recriação, coma versão mais
>   recente da imagem (cuidado com os dados voláteis)

Ainda assim, o [Rancher](http://rancher.com/rancher/) consegue te ajudar a gerir todo o seu parque de containers.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é mais simples utilizar no Rancher e adicionar o programa Prometheus e junto com ele tem o Grafana que possui um sampler de relatórios e dashboards e totalmente 100% com open-source e gratuito.